# Redirecting without query

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to set redirection form `^mysite/` to `www.mynewsite.example`.

The problem is I don't want this direction when is `www.mysite.example?test=test`.

Redirection should  works when client goes by `www.mysite.example`.

I tried to use RewriteRule

```
^mysite.xhtml$ www.mynewsite.example [L,R=301,NC]
```

But it still doesn't work

````
RewriteRule ^mysite.xhtml$ www.mynewsite.example [L,R=301,NC]```
````

I don't want this direction when my URL is `www.mysite.example?test=test`

Comment: See RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to check the query string ( RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING}  ! test=test )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to stop the url redirection when your root url contains `?test=test` querystring

```
RewriteEngine on

#if not ?test=test querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^test=test$ [NC]
#then Redirect the root url to www.newdomain.example
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.newdomain.example/ [L,R]
```

You can replace `test=test` with `test=.+` in the `RewriteCond` above if it's a dynamic value.

`^/?$` matches your root URI ie. `/` . If you want to redirect the entire site then replace it with `^.*$` .